# Accessing HealthMonitoring Provider settings programmatically

Tags: asp.net, configuration, health-monitoring

I have set up ASP.Net health monitoring in web.config:

```
<healthMonitoring enabled="true">
<providers>
<clear />
<add name="CriticalMailEventProvider" type="System.Web.Management.SimpleMailWebEventProvider"
from="appErrors@myhost.com" to="me@myhost.com"
bodyHeader="Application Error!" bodyFooter="Please investigate ASAP." 
subjectPrefix="ERROR: " buffer="true" bufferMode="Critical Notification" 
maxEventLength="8192" maxMessagesPerNotification="1"
/>
</providers></healthMonitoring>
```

And I am attempting to read the configuration of this provider in code:

```
Dim HealthMonitoring As System.Web.Configuration.HealthMonitoringSection
Dim ToAddress As String
HealthMonitoring = CType(WebConfigurationManager.GetWebApplicationSection("system.web/healthMonitoring"), HealthMonitoringSection)
ToAddress = HealthMonitoring.Providers(0).ElementInformation.Properties("to").Value.ToString
```

[Note: not actual production code, hard-coded & condensed for brevity]
**The problem:** While the ElementInformation.Properties collection contains the keys as expected, the Value is "Nothing" and so are all other properties of "Properties("to")".
How can I access the settings of the Provider?

Comment: anysolution , any sample complete code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In C#:

```
HealthMonitoringSection section = WebConfigurationManager.GetWebApplicationSection("system.web/healthMonitoring") as HealthMonitoringSection;
```

**section.Providers[3].Parameters["to"]** returns **"me@myhost.com"**.

(3 assumes that the providers list wasn't cleared in web.config.)

Comment: I'm sure I tried the Parameters collection but it works now, cheers.

Answer (score 0):

I've resorted to reading the web.config file as an XML document and using the nodes selected with the XPath: configuration/system.web/healthMonitoring/providers/*[@name]

Answer (score 0):

Based on AUSteve's answer I used the below code.

```
Dim xmldoc As New System.Xml.XmlDocument
xmldoc.Load(HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("Web.config"))
Dim xmlnsManager As System.Xml.XmlNamespaceManager = New System.Xml.XmlNamespaceManager(xmldoc.NameTable)
xmlnsManager.AddNamespace("nc", "http://schemas.microsoft.com/.NetConfiguration/v2.0")

Dim emailTo As String = xmldoc.SelectSingleNode("/configuration/system.web/healthMonitoring/providers/add", xmlnsManager).Attributes("to").Value.ToString
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Initialize method to access the attributes you specified in the web.config. Just access the NameValueCollection (and remove it your custom attributes before base.Initialize is being called)

This article shows a C# implementation: http://www.tomot.de/en-us/article/6/asp.net/how-to-create-a-custom-healthmonitoring-provider-that-sends-e-mails